# Make h2 in the center of a div and an img on the right of the text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put 2 "h1" tags in the center of the page and a logo to the right of the "h1"tags. I am so frustrated because I could not solve it without using absolute positioning. I do not want to use absolute positioning because if the resolution of the browser changes, it would look totally different. Below is what I am trying to do:[image]

I am able to get the Mars Postal to the center of the div by using "text-align: center;". But I am not able to get the img next to it without using absolute positioning. Below is the code I am using right now:

**HTML:**

```
        <div id="logo">             
            <h1>Mars Postal</h1>
        </div>
        <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="img from mars" title="mars"/>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo{
width: 300px;
margin: 0 auto; 
background-color:#FFFFFF;
```

}

```
#logo h1{
font-size: 90px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
```

}

I have tried to put the img between the 2 "h1" div, but that didn't work. And I tried to use float: right for the img, and it went down to the nav bar. So I hope somebody can shed some light for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you could do something along the lines of: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVTE5/)

```
img {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code , you can do this :
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/DKnqJ/

```
#logo {
  text-align:center;
}
h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:300px;
}
#logo img {
  margin-right:-200px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Else from a code with logo included in title, you can make it like this : :

```
<div id="logo">             
            <h1>            
            <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="img from mars" title="mars"/>            
            Mars Postal          
            </h1> 
        </div>
```

and CSS

```
#logo {             
      text-align:center;             
      }             
#logo h1 img  {            
      float:right;            
      }
#logo h1 {             
      margin:0;           
      /*optionnal*/             
      line-height:/* height of logo img */            
      }
```

If `h1` is 300px wide and centered, to see logo **aside the 300px** box (`h1`):

```
#logo {             
          text-align:center;             
          }             
    #logo h1 img  {            
          float:right;
margin-right:-200px ; /* if image is 200px width , else adapt negative margin to width*/            
          }
    #logo h1 {             
          width:300px;             
          margin:0 auto;           
          /*optionnal*/             
          line-height:/* height of logo img */            
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

h1 is a block level tag, so it takes up the full width of the container. Move the image back into the #logodiv. Depending on how you want the image to behave:

```
#logo{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    text-align:center;
}
#logo img{
    float: right;
}
#logo h1{
     display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; 
}
```

Or...

```
#logo{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background-color:#FFFFFF; 
    text-align:center;
}
#logo img{
    display:inline;
}
#logo h1{
     display: inline;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the image a background image of the header tag and position it to the right with no repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:
**HTML**

```
<h1><img src="images/img.jpg">Mars<br>Postal</h1>
```

**css**

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;  
    position: relative; //the elelement with abslolute position will be positioned relative to this element
}

img {  
    position: absolute; //this element will be positioned relative to it's parent with relative position
    right: 0;
}
```

See live demo [here](http://codepen.io/mojtaba/pen/LybGt/)